# Method reference to instance method using instance type

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, method-reference

I was referring to [this](https://www.codementor.io/eh3rrera/using-java-8-method-reference-du10866vx) article, which states that we can refer instance method using two ways:

1. Using instance

   ```
   obj::instanceMethod
   ```
2. Using instance type

   ```
   ObjectType::instanceMethod
   ```

First I am easy to verify with my simple example:

```
class DummyConsumer
{
    public void consume(String a)
    {
        System.out.println("Counsumed " + a);
    }
}

DummyConsumer d = new DummyConsumer();
Consumer<String> c1 = d::consume;     //method reference
Consumer<String> c2 = (s) -> d.consume(s);  //lambda expression
c1.accept("s");
c2.accept("d");
```

But I am not able to do same with `ObjectType::instanceMethod`. The example given on that page is confusing me a lot and is as follows:

```
class Shipment {
  public double calculateWeight() { return 0d; }
}

public List<Double> calculateOnShipments(List<Shipment> l, Function<Shipment, Double> f) {
    List<Double> results = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Shipment s : l) {
      results.add(f.apply(s));
    }
    return results;
}
calculateOnShipments(l, s -> s.calculateWeight()); //lambda expression
calculateOnShipments(l, Shipment::calculateWeight); //method reference
```

Notice `Shipment::calculateWeight` on last line above. Can someone help me imitate this with my Consumer example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you can use `ObjectType::instanceMethod` seemingly without an instance is because that method reference represents a method that accepts `ObjectType` as a parameter, followed by parameters of the `instanceMethod`.

```
class A {
    public void f(String s) {}
}
```

Here, You can think of `A::f` as representing a "static" method like this:

```
public static void f(A a, String s) {}
```

So in your example, you need a `BiConsumer` to represent a method accepting two parameters and returning nothing:

```
BiConsumer<DummyConsumer, String> c = DummyConsumer::consume;
```

In the `Shipment` case, `Shipment::calculateWeight` represents a "static" method like this:

```
public static double calculateWeight(Shipment s) { ... }
```

This is why `Shipment::calculateWeight` can be represented by `Function<Shipment, Double>`.

So in general, you just need to first figure out what kind of method does a method reference represent, and find a functional interface that represents that kind of method. Sometimes, you need to create a functional interface yourself!